# How to use Jenkins plugins with no pipeline support?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a plugin that I would like to call from a pipeline Jenkinsfile, but the plugin does not have pipeline support so it does not show up in the snippet generator.

Is it still possible to use this plugin with a pipeline job; if so, how?

Specifically, the plugin I'm trying to use is the [Nexus IQ plugin](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213463638-How-do-I-download-and-install-the-Nexus-IQ-Server-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

From a Pipeline job you could use `build('job-name')` to build a Freestyle job which uses that plugin.

But unless the plugin has added Pipeline support (which is usually [pretty simple](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/DEVGUIDE.md)), you can't use it in a Pipeline job.

Given that this particular plugin is closed-source, and still appears to be compatible with Hudson(!), there might not be much hope.  You'd have to ask the plugin maintainers to add support.