# Jenkins Text finder Plugin, How can I use this plugin with jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying write a jenkinsfile using [Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin), but I don't know exactly how it works.

Here's my code:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "master"
        }            
    }
    stages {
        stage('CHECKOUT') {
            steps{
                script{
                    echo "##[1 / 4] ERROR"
                }
                publishers {
                    textFinder("*ERROR*", '', true, false, true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mghicks already mentions, not every plugin supports Jenkins pipelines. In this case the Text Finder plugin is not supporting it. 
You can for example write your own groovy function for it:

For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "master"
        }            
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Check logs') {
            steps {
                filterLogs ('ERROR', 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are calling a function filterLogs and we provide the parameters 'ERROR' (search for the word ERROR in your logs) and we define the occurence of the word 'ERROR' (when the word ERROR is there 2 times, than make the job unstable):

Our filterLogs function looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

def call(String filter_string, int occurrence) {
    def logs = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10000).join('\n')
    int count = StringUtils.countMatches(logs, filter_string);
    if (count > occurrence -1) {
        currentBuild.result='UNSTABLE'
    }
}
```

You can also just implement the function just inside your pipeline if you are not using shared libraries or something.

Comment: TextFinder supports now pipelines: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34983

Comment: This is not really relevant for Jenkins pipelines. the mentioned below is correct. This solution requires you to get into java under the hood, which is an evil step for people who are running other languages and deployments.

Comment: Now there is indeed a better solution below. But this solution didn't exist 2 years ago. Writing groovy scripts for your pipelines has no disadvantage and has nothing to do with which language you are building/deploying. Jenkins supports a shared library setup in which you can write reusable .groovy scripts so you can manage the magic in one place and resuse it in multiple pipelines: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 3):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "master"
        }            
    }
    stages {
        stage('CHECKOUT') {
            steps{
                script{
                    echo "##[1 / 4] ERROR"
                }
                publishers {
                    findText regexp: failure, alsoCheckConsoleOutput: true notBuiltIfFound: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Plugins need to enable pipeline support](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/)--it's not automatic.  Given the Text Finder plugin hasn't been updated since Jan 2014, and I don't see it in the list of [pipeline steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/), it simply may not be possible.  For a potential workaround see [How to use Jenkins plugins with no pipeline support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903815/how-to-use-jenkins-plugins-with-no-pipeline-support)

Comment: Quite a strange link to workaround. It states "No. You can't".

Comment: @AndreyRegentov I agree. I wonder if anyone is able to see the history of that question--did it used to have another answer?  I don't think I would have linked to that as it looks today.

Comment: This plugin is now on the supported list: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/text-finder/

Comment: Thanks, @denu !  WRT the workaround, it says: "From a Pipeline job you could use build('job-name') to build a Freestyle job which uses that plugin."  Not that it's needed anymore.