# Is it possible to bubble up a nodejs exit code in jenkins powershell and use that exit code to set build status?

Tags: node.js, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a nodeJS script that returns non-zero exit codes and I'm running this script with Powershell plugin in Jenkins in a pipeline job. I would like to use these exit codes in the pipeline to set build statuses. I can see the non-zero exit codes e.g. with echo in powershell, but using exit $LastExitCode always exits with code 1.

Here's what I currently have:

```
 def status = powershell(returnStatus: true, script: '''
    try{
        node foo.js
        echo $LastExitCode
        exit $LastExitCode
    } catch {
        exit 0
    }
''')
println status
if(status == 666) {
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
    return
} else if(status == 1) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    return
} else {
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
    return
}
```

The "foo.js" file there is very simple:

```
console.log("Hello from a js file!");
process.exit(666);
```

That above code sets build status to failure, since `println status` prints "1". So, my question is that is it even possible to bubble the non-zero custom exit codes to be used in the pipeline code through Powershell plugin somehow? Or is there some other way to achieve this, totally different from what I'm trying to do here?

**UPDATE:**
Eventually I scrapped the idea of exit codes for now, and went with an even uglier, hackier way :-(

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
def filterLogs(String filter_string, int occurrence) {
    def logs = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10000).join('\n')
    int count = StringUtils.countMatches(logs, filter_string);
    if (count > occurrence -1) {
        currentBuild.result='UNSTABLE'
    }
}
```

And later in the pipeline after the nodeJS script has run:

```
stage ('Check logs') {
    steps {
        filterLogs ('Some specific string I console.log from NodeJS', 1)
    }
}
```

This solution I found here [Jenkins Text finder Plugin, How can I use this plugin with jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450640/jenkins-text-finder-plugin-how-can-i-use-this-plugin-with-jenkinsfile) as an answer to that question.

If that's the only way, I guess I'll have to live with that then.

Comment: You can use `returnStdout` instead of `returnStatus`, but that would require you to limit printing. Or maybe a bit of .contains() chaos.

Comment: @kirkpatt thank you for your comment! Indeed using returnStdout could be used, but that would then prevent console.logs and anything from printing :( 

What did you mean by .contains() chaos?

Comment: I imagine if you need the return codes from a command you could, in the script, echo a very specific string like `MYERRORCODE: 666` or `MYERRORCODE: 1` to pull out both your exit code and the rest of your output.

Disgusting hackery, but if nothing else...